# Find the condition that the expressions $ax^2+2hxy+by^2$,$a'x^2+2h'xy+b'y^2$ may be respectively divisible by factors of the form $y-mx$, $my+x$ .

Tags: functions, quadratics

> Find the condition that the expressions $ax^2+2hxy+by^2$,$a'x^2+2h'xy+b'y^2$ may be respectively divisible by factors of the form $y-mx$, $my+x$ .

**What I've tried:**

Let $p(x,y) = ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2$ and $q(x,y) = a'x^2 + 2h'xy +b'y^2$ and $y-mx$, $my+x$ be factors of $p(x,y)$ and $q(x,y)$ respectively.

Now putting $y = mx$ in $p(x,y)$ , I got :
$x^2(a + 2hm + bm^2x^2) = 0$ or, $bm^2 + 2hm + a = 0$ ...(i)

And putting $x = -my$ in $q(x,y)$ , I got :
$y^2(a'm^2 - 2h'm + b') = 0$ or, $a'm^2 - 2h'm + b' = 0$ ...(ii)

From (i) and (ii), $aa' + 2hma' + 2h'mb - bb' = 0$

*But the required condition is $(aa' - bb')^2 + 4(ha'+h'b)(hb' + h'a) = 0$*

Comment: You leaved the right tracks when saying ""From (i) to (ii),..." What you must look for is *eliminate* $m$ between (i) and (ii), i.e. find under which condition on $a,b,a',b',h,h'$ there exists an $$ such that (i) and (ii).

Comment: @AnneBauval first of all tell me mam why there's a need to eliminate m and what's wrong with my derived condition 

Comment: "First of all", your derived condition is correct but off topic. Secondly, you need to (=my hint is) eliminate $m$ because *you* introduced it. The question is: give a (necessary and sufficient) condition (on $a,b,a',b',h,h'$). And thirdly, replace "First of all tell me mam" with "Please", and don't overuse emoticons. (Incidentally, there is a misprint in my first comment: an $m$ is missing between the two dollar signs.)

Comment: Alt. hint: think at why the condition is equivalent to the two quadratics $ax^2+2hx+b$ and $b'x^2-2h'x+a'$ having a common root, then you'll find several duplicates around MSE.

Comment: @AnneBauval so sorry mam

Comment: @dxiv sorry but what the above problem have to do with quadratics with common roots ?

Comment: @Ash_Blanc $ax^2+2hxy+by^2 = y^2\big(a\frac{x^2}{y^2} + 2h\frac{x}{y} + b\big)$ is divisible by $y-mx$ iff $\frac{x}{y} = \frac{1}{m}$ is a root, or, equivalently, if $at^2 + 2ht + b$ has $t = \dfrac{1}{m}$ as a root.

Comment: Yeah it's a good way to work with the problem but how to continue with this approach can u please elaborate it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the resultant obtained from a pair of quadratic polynomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4118613/how-is-the-resultant-obtained-from-a-pair-of-quadratic-polynomials)

Comment: @AnneBauval sorry mam but that doesn't actually seems to be helpful even 'cause it's not abstract algebra and abstract algebra is beyond high school level algebra

Comment: @Ash_Blanc I happen to have posted the accepted answer to the question Anne Bauval linked, and there is no *abstract algebra* there. It reduces to a linear system having determinant zero, which is certainly within reach of high school algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
\begin{eqnarray}
bm^2+2hm+a& =& 0
\\a'm^2-2h'm+b' &=& 0,
\end{eqnarray}
we need to eliminate $m$ to get a single equation in the coefficients. We could do this directly by solving one equation for $m$ using the quadratic formula, then plugging that value into the other. However, the square roots will make the algebra in that second step messy. You can try it if you like--it'll get the same solution--but there's a better way.

First, note that if $b m^2 + 2hm + a = 0$ and $a'm^2 - 2h'm + b' = 0$, then it is also true that $p ( m^2 + 2hm + a) + q (a'm^2 - 2h'm + b') = 0$ for any $p,q$. With the proper choice of $p$ and $q$, we can simplify the dependence on $m$ by getting rid of either the linear term or the quadratic term. To get rid of the quadratic term, we use $p = a'$ and $q = -b$. To get rid of the linear term, we use $p = h'$ and $q=h$. This gives
\begin{eqnarray}
2(a'h+bh')m + aa'-bb' &=& 0\\
(a'h+ bh')m^2 + ah'+b'h &=& 0.
\end{eqnarray}
Multiplying the second equation by $4(a'h + bh')$ and rearranging the first gives the more suggestive form
\begin{eqnarray}
2(a'h+bh')m &=& bb'-aa'\\
\left[2(a'h+ bh')m\right]^2 &+& 4(a'h + bh')(ah'+b'h)= 0.
\end{eqnarray}
From which we clearly have
$$
\left(bb'-aa'\right)^2 + 4(a'h + bh')(ah'+b'h)= 0,
$$
which is the same as the given result because $(bb'-aa')^2 = (aa'-bb')^2$.