# Usages of Sylvester matrix

Tags: polynomials, reference-request

The Sylvester matrix of two polynomials $f = \sum^n_{i = 0} a_ix^i$ and $g = \sum^m_{i = 0} b_ix^i$ is defined as

$$S(f, g) := \begin{bmatrix}a_n & a_{n - 1} & \cdots & a_0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & a_n & \cdots & a_1 & a_0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & a_0 \\ b_m & b_{m - 1} & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & b_m & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & b_0\end{bmatrix}$$

Besides being used to define the resultant of two polynomials $\left(\operatorname{Res}(f, g) := \det{S(f, g)}\right)$, where else is the Sylvester matrix used?

Comment: The [applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix#Applications) section on wikipedia provides a few pointers. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4127665/291201) is a worked out example which derives a (simple) Sylvester matrix by hand, without using the associated theory.